# "special" filesystems

Tags: mount

When running mount, I get a list of mounted "filesystems". Some of them do not seem to be real filesystems. They have types, like:

- devtmpfs
- devpts
- securityfs
- cgroup
- cgroup2
- pstore
- debugfs
- hugetlbfs
- mqueue
- fusectl
- squashfs

Is there a comprehensive list of these filesystems somewhere? (I already excluded the ones included in the quite good [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system#Device_file_systems) article from this question).

Is there a way to only print "real" file systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the FS types that `mount` lists with the option `-t`:

```
mount -t ext3,ext2,ext4,squashfs,vfat,fuseblk
```

When you look up that option in the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html#COMMAND-LINE_OPTIONS) it points you to [`/proc/filesystems`](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-filesystems.html), where you can find the list of all supported types; [virtual filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system) (the ones you would like to hide) are prefixed with "nodev" there.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you know what they're used for, "I already deleted the ones included in the quite good wikipedia article" seems unwise.

OTOH, finding mounted real drives is easy:

```
mount | grep -E '^/dev'
```

Comment: ....I mean I excluded them from my question.